# Running Unit Tests as application in Docker Container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, junit5

We have quite a lot of end-2-end tests implemented using JUnit being executed after our application-stack has been deployed on kubernetes. As there are many use cases outside the build process we would like to execute those tests in a container. The idea is to wrap an application around those tests and ship them as image to whoever wants to execute tests on his system.

As always it seemed to be quite easy to *just* write some small wrapper application around unit tests and jib them into a container. However, the deeper you go into it, the more things pop up. So I wonder: Is there maybe already some App / Framework / whatever allowing me to add my unit tests into it and ensuring:

- tests can be shipped via an image
- ensuring that application can be meaningfully executed from within an kubernetes environment
- provide some nice test reporting
- ensuring tests won't get executed multiple times in parallel
- handling long running tests

And handling all the other things I didn't think about when saying: "Ah, that easy, I do it"

Comment: Use the Maven official image, add all your sources to it and execute `mvn test` in it.

Comment: You can add these stages into Jenkins pipeline and execute in Kubernetes clusters in multiple envs.